# Tensorflow, how to pass MultiRNN state in feed_dict

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to make a generative RNN model in tensorflow. What is annoying me is that with the new switch to state_is_tupe being true by default in the RNN library, I am having a hard time finding the best way to save state between batches.  I know I can change it back to being False but I don't want to do it since it is deprecated.  When I am done with the training I need to be able to perserve the hidden states between calls to session.run since I will be generating the sequences one sample at a time.  I figured out that I can return the state of the rnn as follows.

```
        rnn = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells)  
        zero_state = rnn.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
        output, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(rnn, self.input_sound, initial_state = zero_state)
        sess = tf.Session()
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        state_output = sess.run(final_state, feed_dict = {self.input_sound: np.zeros((64, 32, 512))})
```

This would be great but the issue emerges when I want to pass state_output back into the model.  Since a placeholder can only be a tensor object I can't pass it back the state_output tupel.

I am looking for a very generic solution.  The rnn could be a MultiRNNCell or a single LSTMCell or any other combination imaginable.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  I used the following code to flatten the state tuples into a single 1D tensor.  I can than chop it up when I pass it back into the model according to the size specification of the rnn cell.

```
def flatten_state_tupel(x):
    result = []
    for x_ in x:
        if isinstance(x_, tf.Tensor) or not hasattr(x_, '__iter__'):
            result.append(x_)
        else:
            result.extend(flatten_state_tupel(x_))
    return result

def pack_state_tupel(state):
    return tf.concat(0, [tf.reshape(s, (-1,)) for s in flatten_state_tupel(state)])

def unpack_state_tupel(state, size):
    state = tf.reshape(state, (-1, tf.reduce_sum(flatten_state_tupel(size))))
    def _make_state_tupel(sz, i):
        if hasattr(sz, '__iter__'):
            result = []
            for s in sz:
                base_index, y = _make_state_tupel(s, i)
                result.append(y)
            return base_index, tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(*result) if isinstance(sz, tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple) else tuple(result)
        else:
            return i + sz, state[..., i : i + sz]
    return _make_state_tupel(size, 0)[-1]
```

I use the functions as follows.

```
rnn = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells)  
zero_state = pack_state_tupel(rnn.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32))
self.initial_state = tf.placeholder_with_default(zero_state, None)

output, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(rnn, self.input_sound, initial_state = unpack_state_tupel(self.initial_state, rnn.state_size))

packed_state = pack_state_tupel(final_state)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

state_output = sess.run(packed_state, feed_dict = {self.input_sound: np.zeros((64, 32, 512))})
print(state_output.shape)
state_output = sess.run(packed_state, feed_dict = {self.input_sound: np.zeros((64, 32, 512)), self.initial_state: np.zeros(state_output.shape[0])})
print(state_output)
```

This way it will zero the state if I do not pass anything (which will be the case during training) however I can save and pass the state between batches during generation.